# Wiris editor font settings not working

Tags: web-applications, editor, text-editor

I'm using Wiris editor in one of my mvc web application. Currently I'm generating wiris images with the help of image service call (http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/render?mml=" + Url.Encode(mathML)). It is possible to pass font configuration parameters directly with this url.I was able to set a custom font size (say 48) while making the service call and was able to generate the image successfully.

According to the document, ‘fontIdent’ and  ‘fontNumber’ parameters are used to set font family or typeface. For example, to render variables and numbers with Verdana font I have appended the following string with the encoded mathML expression (&fontIdent=verdana & fontNumber=verdana). But it doesn't work. In the documentation, they said that this will only work if Verdana is installed on the server that hosts WIRIS editor. Is this is the reason behind the issue?

Suppose if I need to use a custom font, do I need to purchase Wiris plugin and installed on a server (my own server or wiris.net). And then I have to install that custom font on that server? Please assist..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We believe you may be looking at an old WIRIS documentation since fontIdent and fontNumber are not currently supported in WIRIS editor.
This is the list of available parameters: http://www.wiris.com/en/editor/docs/reference/parameters

We understand you are using the plugin in SaaS mode (connecting to the WIRIS editor server components in our servers). 
In order to use a custom font you would need to install the plugin **and** the server components in your server.